# Can not create osgQt (OpenSceneGraph QT lib) library after osg 3.2 compile with cmake GUI

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012, cmake, openscenegraph

I have tried to build OpenSceneGraph (OSG) Visual Studio 2012 Project after OSG is compiled successful with cmake. However while OSG is being built VS2012, it gives error. The error is :

```
Generating __/__/include/osgQt/moc_QGraphicsViewAdapter.cpp
3>  moc: Too many input files specified
3>  Usage: C:\Qt\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\bin\moc.exe [options] [header-file] [@option file]
3>  Qt Meta Object Compiler version 67 (Qt 5.2.1)

 ...
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(172,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.
```

why does it give this error?
Thank you very much

Comment: I bet you have quotes in automoc call.

Comment: This could be a Qt4/Qt5 problem; I ran into the same issue on Linux when trying to build OSG for the first time after moving to Qt5.